# xcode: select expressions shortcut

Tags: xcode, keyboard-shortcuts

With Eclipse/Java one of the shortcuts I used a lot was selecting expressions.  alt+shift+up would increase selection to the next parent/enclosing expression, alt+shift+down would bring it back down.

Is there anything like this for XCode/Objective-C.  What about when using vi?

Comment: Now in Xcode 4.4, you can edit your shortcuts in Xcode preferences. Go to key binding tab, search for "Move Expression Left Extending Selection", and create a keyboard shortcut for it.

Comment: None of the "Move Expression..." commands seem to have any effect for me (Xcode 4.5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't seem to be any way to do this, even in XC4.  Sad.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about any keyboard shortcuts, but in XCode double-clicking a parentheses, curly bracket, square bracket, or quote will select the corresponding expression/block.